# Passenger is listing all files instead of running my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger, vhosts

I'm trying to add the Rails application to the a directory of another application and for some reason the rails application is not rendering

Here's a [link](http://transprintusa.com/design/) to my application

Here's VHOST

```
<VirtualHost 184.106.111.142:80>
     ServerAdmin joe@joe.com
     ServerName transprintusa.com/design
     # ServerAlias
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/current/public
     ErrorLog /srv/www/design.transprintusa.com/logs/error.log
     RailsEnv production
     <Directory "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/current/public">
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but the Rails application is showing all the files.

Passenger and everything is installed on this server because the Rails site was at design.transprintusa.com. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

If there is anything I can give to help anyone help me

**UPDATE - Here is my new VHOST and still displays the rails files**

```
<VirtualHost 184.106.111.142:80>
   ServerAdmin jom@jom.com
   ServerName transprintusa.com
   ServerAlias www.transprintusa.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/
   ErrorLog /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/">
             AllowOverride all
             Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
RailsBaseURI /rails
 <Directory /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design>
     Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work in this way. The `ServerName` [must be a hostname](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername).

You must set `ServerName transprintusa.com`, then use the `Location` or `Directory` directive to enable passenger when the request matches given location.

See [Deploying to a sub URI](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) from the Passenger documentation.

Comment: But i already have another vhost with the transprintusa.com for the main site

Comment: You must merge everything into that virtual host.

Comment: so from your link it looks like all i add is this portion    RailsBaseURI /rails                   # <-- These lines have
    <Directory /websites/phusion/rails>   # <-- been added.
        Options -MultiViews               # <--
    </Directory>

Comment: thanks again @Simone now I am getting a different error on locating the application, any ideas on how to fix